# Image display on tkinter canvas not working

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

I am trying to write a simple paint program and I have fully functioning save and draw features, though in the open button's method, the msg.create_image function isnt showing the image. THere is no error, just the GUI and a blank large canvas.
Here is my code in python 2.7.5 with PIL 1.1.7 written on a windows 7 64 bit and run correctly on both the windows and a Mac running OS X Mountain Lion, 10.9
PS I apologize for identations... They may be off due to copying it to this post.
Thanks

Comment: Don't apologize for identations but correct this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep a reference to the image, tk_im, because it is garbage collected once the function exits.  One way is to add it to the Canvas instance.

```
 def opens():
    global img,msg,idraw
    filename = askopenfilename()
    im = Image.open(filename)
    msg.tk_im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)              ## <------------
    a=msg.create_image(0,0,image=msg.tk_im)
    idraw=ImageDraw.Draw(im)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create ImageTk.PhotoImage in function and you assign it to local variable it is destroyed by garbage collector when you leave that function. And that is why you do not see the image.

You have to assign it to global variable

```
tk_im = None

def opens():
    global img,msg,idraw

    global tk_im

    filename = askopenfilename()
    im = Image.open(filename)
    tk_im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    a = msg.create_image(0,0,image=tk_im)
    idraw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
```

If you are going to add more images you have to remember all of them on global list.

```
tk_im = []

def opens():
    global img,msg,idraw

    global tk_im

    filename = askopenfilename()
    im = Image.open(filename)

    tk_im.append( ImageTk.PhotoImage(im) )

    a = msg.create_image(0,0, image=tk_im[-1] )
    idraw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
```