# Adding an Image to a Canvas using askopenfilename()

Tags: python, image, tkinter, filedialog

I'm trying to get a `.gif` image to go into a canvas after being selected from my PC using `filedialog.askopenfilename()`. The canvas will take the image if I:

1. Don't put it in a `def` and
2. Do not use the `filedialog`, but I can't see why this would not work...

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
root.geometry("600x600")
root.config(background="#FFFFFF")

canvas = Canvas(width=200,height=200)
canvas.grid(row=0,column=0)


def create_image():
    profileimage = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    i = PhotoImage(file=profileimage)
    canvas.create_image(0,0,image=i)

b = Button(text="Click", command=create_image).grid(row=1,column=0)
```

Comment: Check if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20061396/image-display-on-tkinter-canvas-not-working

Comment: Works now, thank you Vinkal!

Answer (score 1):

```
global i       
def create_image(self): 
    global i
    profileimage = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    i = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(profileimage))
    canvas.create_image(0,0,image=i)
```

Without referencing the image in a global variable, the image is stored in a local variable of the function that gets cleared by the garbage collector.